# .htaccess rule to redirect to default API version

Tags: php, api, .htaccess

In my PHP API, I would like to redirect requests that don't include a version number to a default version.

So for example, a request to

```
/api/<endpoint>
```

will redirect to

```
/api/v2/<endpoint>
```

if v2 is the default version for the API. Requests that include a version number should work as normal.

The file structure is like this:

- api

  - v1
  - v2

    - (endpoints)

I'm struggling to understand the .htaccess syntax, and what Apache expression is required. What I've tried so far is to check if the URL contains a version number in it:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect requests from /api/ to current version of the API
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !^(v[0-9])$
RewriteRule ^?$ /v1/$1
```

Does anyone have experience with this issue or know how to go about solving it?

Comment: Do you mean to redirect `/api/{anything but v2}` to `/api/v2/anything` ?

Comment: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` is the path to the root directory of your application, that does not even contain any `vX`. You’d want to look at REQUEST_URI if you want to check on anything in the actual URL path.

Comment: @AmitVerma pretty much, but I mean to rewrite ```/api/{anything but v[0-9]}```, so that any request without a version number is rewritten to the default API version (which in this example is v2).

Comment: @CBroe ok thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean an internal rewrite, as opposed to an external 3xx "redirect"?

You could do something like the following using mod_rewrite in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
# Set env var to default API version
SetEnvIf ^ ^ DEFAULT_API_VERSION=2

# Rewrite requests from /api/ to default version of the API if not explicitly set
RewriteRule ^api/(?!v\d+/)(.*) /api/v${ENV:DEFAULT_API_VERSION}/$1 [L]
```

The environment variable is just a convenience to avoid having to modify the later rule.

The complete "version" path segment is assumed to be `v` followed by any number of digits, followed by a slash.

This uses a negative lookahead to avoid matching URLs that already contain a version string as the second path segment. Otherwise the URL-path after `/api/` is captured in the `$1` backreference and used in the *substitution* string.

The above will rewrite as follows:

- `/api/v1/<endpoint>` - no change
- `/api/<endpoint>` - rewrite to `/api/v2/<endpoint>`
- `/api/` - rewrite to `/api/v2/`
- `/api/v1234/` - no change
- `/api/v1234` (no trailing slash) - rewrite to `/api/v2/v1234`
- `/api/v2.1234/foo` - rewrite to `/api/v2/v2.1234/foo`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did mean internal rewrite instead of an external redirect. I tried using your code in a .htaccess file in the root folder of my project, but I was having some trouble with it. It comes up with a 404 error for requests that exclude the version number. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Where are you putting these directives? Order is important. These directives will need to go near the top. However, it also depends on your API and how you are routing your URLs. Presumably you also have a front-controller? How does your API determine the route/endpoint? For instance, if in your PHP code you are checking the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal then this will still contain the URL _before_ it was rewritten (ie. the URL that was requested) and not the URL with the version number.

Comment: It turns out the new rule was interfering with another .htaccess directive I had in a subfolder, and your code works just fine. Thank you for answering my question and helping me.